# In how many different ways can you invest 20,000 onto five funds in increments of 1,000?

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many different ways can you invest 20,000 onto five funds in increments of 1,000?
>
> (Question 4.24 from Timothy Falcon Crack)

The answer says it is $5^{20}$, but I thought of this as a "stars and bars" type of problem and said it was $\binom{24}{4}$.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your first thousand can be invested in 1 of 5 funds. Your second thousand also have 1 of 5 possibilities....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are thinking that each $1000$ is identical, so all that matters is how much money you put into each fund.  If they are, your answer is correct.  $5^{20}$ would be correct if the $1000$s were distinct.  If you invested $1000$ per month for $20$ months it matters which $1000$ goes into which fund.  They are different problems with different answers.  Check the wording of the problem for whether the $1000$s are identical or distinct.

Comment: Thanks! That cleared it up. Not sure why the book didn't go into detail